# p7zip installs, but doesn't install? (7za: command not found)

Tags: 7-zip

I've uploaded it to /usr/local and used ./install.sh with ssh. I get the following:

```
- installing /usr/local/man/man1/7z.1
- installing /usr/local/man/man1/7za.1
- installing /usr/local/man/man1/7zr.1
- installing /usr/local/share/doc/p7zip/README
- installing /usr/local/share/doc/p7zip/ChangeLog
- installing HTML help in /usr/local/share/doc/p7zip/DOCS
```

This is what I *should* be getting right?

However, when trying to use 7za, it's constantly telling me 'command not found'.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Some else I also have to do?

Comment: You question isn't about programming, it's about using somebody else's program.  Ask on SuperUser.

Comment: It's about installing applications on a server with SSH, I think that counts enough to be here.

Comment: How is that programming?